# Getting started with Data Mining

Tags: reference-request, data-mining

This is the first time that I'm looking in depth into the topic, although I've always been curious.
Could someone let me know about online resources (courses, tutorials, etc) and books that cover the basics of the topic?
I'd like to explore both the theoretical part and the more practical part of Data Mining.

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/datasci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques](http://akademik.maltepe.edu.tr/~kadirerdem/772s_Data.Mining.Concepts.and.Techniques.2nd.Ed.pdf).

To see data mining algorithms in practice you can use [Weka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29).

Answer (score 0):

- Microsoft has a brief [datamining tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167167.aspx) wrt SQL server; note also they have a [free version of SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database/free-database.aspx) available.
- [A Data Mining Tutorial](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~steve/pdcn.pdf), Cooperative Research Center for Advanced Computational Systems, by Williams/Hegland/Roberts, Australian National University. 57 slide presentation.